# MirroredStrategy without NCCL

Tags: tensorflow

- **Have I written custom code (as opposed to using a stock example script provided in TensorFlow)**: no
- **OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04)**: Windows 10 x64
- **TensorFlow installed from (source or binary)**: binary
- **TensorFlow version (use command below)**: 1.8.0
- **Python version**: 3.6
- **Bazel version (if compiling from source)**: -
- **GCC/Compiler version (if compiling from source)**: -
- **CUDA/cuDNN version**: 9.0
- **GPU model and memory**: 3.5
- **Exact command to reproduce**: simple_tfkeras_example.py

I would like to use MirroredStrategy to use multiple GPUs in the same machine. I tried one of the examples:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/distribute/python/examples/simple_tfkeras_example.py

The result is:
ValueError: Op type not registered 'NcclAllReduce' in binary running on RAID. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. while building NodeDef 'NcclAllReduce'

I am using Windows, therefore Nccl is not available. Is it possible to force TensorFlow not to use this library?

Comment: I have the same problem. https://github.com/andabi/deep-voice-conversion/issues/52

Answer (score 5):

There are some binaries for NCCL on Windows, but they can be quite annoying to deal with.

As an alternative, Tensorflow gives you three other options in MirroredStrategy that are compatible with Windows natively. They are Hierarchical Copy, Reduce to First GPU, and Reduce to CPU. What you are most likely looking for is Hierarchical Copy, but you can test each of them to see what gives you the best result.

If you are using tensorflow versions older than 2.0, you will use tf.contrib.distribute:

```
# Hierarchical Copy
cross_tower_ops = tf.contrib.distribute.AllReduceCrossTowerOps(
        'hierarchical_copy', num_packs=number_of_gpus))
    strategy = tf.contrib.distribute.MirroredStrategy(cross_tower_ops=cross_tower_ops)

# Reduce to First GPU
cross_tower_ops = tf.contrib.distribute. ReductionToOneDeviceCrossTowerOps()
strategy = tf.contrib.distribute.MirroredStrategy(cross_tower_ops=cross_tower_ops)

# Reduce to CPU
cross_tower_ops = tf.contrib.distribute. ReductionToOneDeviceCrossTowerOps(
    reduce_to_device="/device:CPU:0")
strategy = tf.contrib.distribute.MirroredStrategy(cross_tower_ops=cross_tower_ops)
```

After 2.0, you only need to use tf.distribute! Here is an example setting up an Xception model with 2 GPUs:

```
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(devices=["/gpu:0", "/gpu:1"], 
                                          cross_device_ops=tf.distribute.HierarchicalCopyAllReduce())
with strategy.scope():
    parallel_model = Xception(weights=None,
                              input_shape=(299, 299, 3),
                              classes=number_of_classes)
    parallel_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')
```

Comment: `tf.distribute.HierarchicalCopyAllReduce` for TF1.15